# setting multiple highlighters to a jeditorpane

Tags: java, swing, highlighting, jeditorpane

I want to know whether we can set two highlighters to a `JEditorpane` using `sethighlighter(new Highlighter())` method where one is a default highlighter and the other is a underline highlighter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use one highlighter but adding highlights with another `HighlightPainter` to paint your underline.

```
public Object addHighlight(int p0, int p1, HighlightPainter p) throws BadLocationException;
```

Answer (score 2):

[Rectangle Painter](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/28/rectangle-painter/) shows an example of creating a custom HighlightPainter. You should be able to modify it to just do an underline.